# WPF slider with multibinding where single property is delayed

Tags: c#, wpf, slider, delay, multibinding

I'm looking for solution of having slider and textbox bind to single property for quick UI and when it is the same for 3 seconds then another binding. Do you think that something like that is possible?

```
<Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="1000">
   <Slider.Value>
     <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
         <Binding Delay="3000" Path="FrequencyXState"/>
         <Binding Delay="0" Path="FrequencyX" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
     </MultiBinding>
   </Slider.Value>
 </Slider>
```

Currently both notifications gets triggered one after another. The delay property is ignored. And that is an issue.

Comment: Use a MultBindingConverter, and pass in different values for the both of them with the oter variable you want to link to

Comment: This is not solving the issue. I don't mind having twice the same value. I just need to have 1 value delayed by 3 seconds by framework. And property that is suppose to do that is not working. Do you have another proposal?

Comment: What i suggested is for the second value, use a type, eg ...of type is texbox do this, else of type is that, do that

Comment: It is not the solution. I'm looking for something provided by framework to trigger one change immediately and one with delay. I can simulate it by Thread.Sleep/Task.Delay/Timer.Elapsed but that is not what I'm looking for. Current framework provides functionality to delay binding. It seems that it doesn't work for multi-binding. Therefore if there is solution without threading involved it would be great.